# AngularJS directive : controller or link?

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-directive

I wonder what is the most optimized between :
- Define the method 'foo' directly in a child directive
- Define the method 'foo' in controller and required the controller in child directive

Note :
- The child directive only needs the method 'foo'
- The child directive is used 100+ times in a page
- The controller contains many others things

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to define the function in the controller and pass the function into the scope of the directive. That way you'll have one instance of the function and you can use it by referencing it (that will give you a less memory footprint).

But, if you put the function in the directive and use it there (and the function is needed by the directive), then your directive will be like a black box web component and can be used in other projects without having any dependencies.

So, for this, it all depends on what you need. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Of course it depends of the use case but my question is about performance, an "all-in-one" directive is better than a "link to a big controller" directive or not ?

Comment: Then I would suggest linking to the controller, that will give you a less footprint (as I mentioned referencing above).